# QGIS export project as high-res Geotiff

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I have a project on QGIS 2.18 which includes several raster and vectorial layers and need to export the full project as a high resolution Geotiff.

QGIS allows to export project as an image on print composer but it exports a low resolution image.

I am also able to export layer by layer but I need to export the full project as a single file.

Is there any plugin or approach that allows me to achieve that?

Comment: When exporting from the print composer you set a DPI. That controls the resolution of the output.